# What prevents tourists visiting the U.S. from buying firearms?

Tags: united-states, weapons

Imagine an ordinary foreigner, arrived with a simple tourist visa into the US.

In the U.S., there is no personal identification document. Most of the U.S. people doesn't have a passport.

What prevents a simple tourist to go into a weapon shop and buy a rifle?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11341/can-a-tourist-buy-a-gun-in-the-usa

Comment: a weapons shop will require you to show some form of government ID but you can buy a gun from an individual person or at a gun show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[18 USC 922(g)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/922) says that it is illegal for various persons

> to ship or transport in interstate or foreign commerce, or possess in
>   or affecting commerce, any firearm or ammunition; or to receive any
>   firearm or ammunition which has been shipped or transported in
>   interstate or foreign commerce.

(5) refers to "being an alien", specifically one who

> has been admitted to the United States under a nonimmigrant visa (as
>   that term is defined in section 101(a)(26) of the Immigration and
>   Nationality Act (8 U.S.C. 1101(a)(26)))

with an exception

> as provided in subsection (y)(2),

The (y)(2) exceptions covers foreign officials and law enforcement (not a typical tourist), and one who is

> (A) admitted to the United States for lawful hunting or sporting
>   purposes or is in possession of a hunting license or permit lawfully
>   issued in the United States;

which pretty much covers simple tourists, if not typical tourists.

Answer (score 4):

> In the U.S., there is no personal identification document.

That's not really true.  There is no standard personal identification document issued by the *national* government (if you don't count passports), but *state* governments do issue such documents.  The most common is a state-issued driver license, and people who do not drive can be issued a "non-driver ID" that is otherwise similar. Practically every US citizen or resident has one of these documents, and in practice they are used in a similar way to a national ID card.  (You could do an image search to see what they look like.)

In fact, there is an identification requirement for buying firearms; see 
https://www.atf.gov/firearms/qa/what-form-identification-must-licensee-obtain-transferee-firearm.  A state driver license or non-driver ID would be sufficient for this purpose, and that's what most people would use.

The link mentions that a foreign passport would be acceptable identification; but that doesn't mean a foreign tourist could actually buy a gun.  The [answer by user6726](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/24027/576) cites the relevant law that restricts nonimmigrant aliens from firearm purchases.

Comment: Many US residents are present as nonimmigrants, so they are excluded by the statute, but they of course may have driver's licenses.